# Prove that for each $y$ the y-section set $A_y=\{x\in \mathbb{R}: (x,y)\in A\}$ is a Borel measurable subset of $\mathbb{R}$.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, borel-sets

> Suppose $A$ is a Borel measurable subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$. Prove that for each $y$ the y-section set
>   $A_y=\{x\in \mathbb{R}: (x,y)\in A\}$
>   is a Borel measurable subset of $\mathbb{R}$.

I feel like that is not easy to show $A_y$ is closed in $\mathbb{R}$. Any other methods?

Comment: Why would the section be closed? If $A=B(0,1)$ then $A_y$ is always open and only closed for $|y|\ge 1$. See https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1154407/27978/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The claim is **wrong**.

Pick any set $B\subset \mathbb{R}$ which is not measurable.

Let $A = \{0\} \times B \subset \{0\}\times \mathbb{R}$, where the latter is Lebesgue measurable in $\mathbb{R^{2}}$, with zero measure, therefore the first is also Lebesgue measurable in $\mathbb{R^{2}}$ (Lebesgue measure is complete).

By the choice of $B$, we get $A_0$ is not measurable in $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score -1):

Hint: If a property holds on the generating set, then the property holds on all Borel sets. The open boxes $(a,c)\times(b,d)$ generate $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^2)$.

Comment: Sorry, I do not get your point.

Comment: @BobOakley Well does the y section hold in the case I described? If it does, then since the Borel sigma algebra is generated by all open sets and open boxes generate all open sets in $\mathbb{R}^2$

Comment: y-section holds what? I am still confused. I know open boxes generate $\mathcal{B}(R^2)$. But how about its section?

Comment: If a property holds on a generating set, then the property holds for every set in $\mathcal{B}$. The property in this case is that $A_y$ is Borel in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: But we need to prove $A_y$ is Borel in $\mathbb{R}$, isn't it?

Comment: Correct, but we just can get away with just doing it for the simpler case