# Why are progressively measurable processes adapted?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, stochastic-processes

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{A}, P)$ be a filtered probability space with filtration $(\mathcal{F}_t)_{t \ge 0}$.

A process is said to be progressively measurable if the process as a resitriction to $[0,t]$ is $\mathcal{B}([0,t])\otimes \mathcal{F}_t$ measurable. Here the function is given by $X_s(\omega)$.

But why is this process adapted? If I have a set $B$ set in $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$, and take $(X_s(\omega))^{-1}(B)$ I get a set in $\mathcal{B}([0,t])\otimes \mathcal{F}_t$. I can take the intersection of this set with $\{t\}\times\Omega$ and I am still in $\mathcal{B}([0,t])\otimes \mathcal{F}_t$. But how do I know that the collection of the second coordinates is a set in $\mathcal{F}_t$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Progressive measurability means that for each $t\ge 0$ and any $B\in 
\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$, the set
$$
A:=\{(s,\omega):0\le s\le t,\omega\in \Omega, X_s(\omega)\in B\}\in \mathcal{B}([0,t])\otimes \mathcal{F}_t.
$$
This implies that the section $A_t=\{\omega:(t,\omega)\in A\}\in \mathcal{F}_t$ (see, e.g., [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1153161/every-section-of-a-measurable-set-is-measurable-in-the-product-sigma-algebra)).