# Iterative Integration over indicator function of two variables

Tags: integration, probability-theory, measure-theory, conditional-probability

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{A}, \mathbb{P})$ be a probability space and $X, Y$ random variables, mapping from said space to $(\mathcal{X}, \mathcal{C})$ and $(\mathcal{Y}, \mathcal{D})$, respectively.

The following equation should hold:

$$\mathbb{P}_{X, Y}(E) = \int_{\mathcal{X}}\int_{\mathcal{Y}}\chi_{E}(x, y) \mathbb{P}_{Y\mid X}(dy, x) \mathbb{P}_X (dx),$$

where $E\in \mathcal{C}\otimes\mathcal{D}$.

My question is now how one actually integrates iteratively over the indicator function that takes two arguments? So first I would integrate over $\mathcal{Y}$ but what happens with the indicator function in that integration? And what then happens during the second integration, the integration over $\mathcal{X}$?

Comment: $E$ of the form $C \times D$ with measurable $C$ and $D$. What can you say about $\chi_E(x,y)$ in relation to $\chi_C(x)$ and $\chi_D(y)$?

Comment: probably $\chi_{D\times C}$ is the product of $\chi_C$ and $\chi_D$?

Comment: but how does that help me for general sets?

Comment: For generic sets $E$, I think your best chance might be to rewrite $\chi_E(x,y)$ as $\chi_{E_x}(y)$ or $\chi_{E^y}(x)$, where $E_x := \{y' \mid (x, y') \in E\}$ and $E^y := \{x' \mid (x', y) \in E\}$, which are measurable, see this post [Every section of a measurable set is measurable? (in the product sigma-algebra)](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1154407) for a proof (the measures from OP's question are not used in the proof).

Comment: but $\chi_E$ and $\chi_{E_x}$ are not the same, right?

Comment: As functions they're not, but $\chi_E(x,y)$ is equal to $\chi_{E_x}(y)$ because $(x,y) \in E \Leftrightarrow y \in E_x$. Also, the reason I'm leaving these remarks as comments is that I'm not sure myself about whether or not it's really a good answer to your question... Hopefully someone else can answer with more confidence.

Comment: thank you for your help and your honesty!